# How to use optional argument of random.shuffle in Python

Tags: python, random

From the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) of random.shuffle(x[, random]), it says:

> The optional argument random is a 0-argument function returning a random float in [0.0, 1.0); by default, this is the function random()

Could someone please explain what `0-argument function` means and give an example of `random.shuffle()` with the optional argument `random`? I searched but couldn't find any example for that case. Also, what did it mean by "this is the function `random()`"? Does `this` refer to the optional argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means you can pass in the name of a function which does not require an argument.

```
def foo():
    return 0.5
```

is such a function.

```
def bar(limit):
    return limit
```

is not, because it requires an argument `limit`.

Usage example:

```
random.shuffle(itemlist, random=foo)
```

If the input `itemlist` was `[1, 2, 3]` it will now be `[1, 3, 2]`. I have established this experimentally, and I suppose how exactly the shuffle operation uses the output from the random function could change between Python versions.

The default if you don't specify anything is the function `random()`.

One possible use case for this is if you want predictable output e.g. for a test case. Another is if you want nonuniform distribution - for example, a random function which prefers small values over large ones, or implements e.g. Poisson or normal distribution.

Answer (score 2):

A 0-argument function has an empty argument list.

```py
def random_seed():  # Zero arguments here.
  return MY_CONFIG.predictble_random_seed  # Some imaginary config.

random.shuffle(some_list, random_seed)  # Always the same shuffling.
```

The point of this arrangement is to allow to control the predictability of the shuffling. You can return a really random number (from timer, `/dev/urandom`, etc, as `random.random()` does) in production, and a controlled number in a test environment:

```py
def get_random_generator(environment):
  if environment == 'test':
    return lambda: 0.5  # A 0-argument callable returning a constant.
  else:
    return random.random  # A function returning a random number.

# ... 

# The below is predictable when testing in isolation, 
# unpredictable when running in production.
# We suppose that `environment` has values like 'test' and 'prod'.
random.shuffle(entries, get_random_generator(environment))
```

Comment: Thanks, @9000. Your latest edit makes it easier for a newbie like me to understand. Is `MY_CONFIG.predictble_random_seed` an actual Python function?

Comment: @Nemo: No, `MY_CONFIG.predictble_random_seed` is a made-up global variable that might evoke the idea of configuring your code. I'll expand and comment it.

Answer (score 0):

The random parameter is the seed. Then if you always use the same seed, it always reorder your array with the same logic. See the exemple. 5 is at index 4 and go to 0. 6 go to 4 (Old index of 5) then if we reuse the same seed, 6 go the index 0 because 6 is at index 4 like 5 at the first shuffle

Exemple:

```
>>> import random
>>> r = random.random()
>>> r
0.4309619702601998
>>> x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> random.shuffle(x, lambda: r)
>>> x
[5, 1, 4, 2, 6, 3]
>>> random.shuffle(x, lambda: r)
>>> x
[6, 5, 2, 1, 3, 4]
>>> x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> random.shuffle(x, lambda: r)
>>> x
[5, 1, 4, 2, 6, 3]
```

[Source](https://www.science-emergence.com/Articles/M%C3%A9langer-al%C3%A9atoirement-les-%C3%A9l%C3%A9ments-dune-liste-sous-python/)

Comment: What your anser is missing is an explanation of "what 0-argument function means", which the author is asking.

Comment: Yes, they are part of what I'm looking for (example of random.shuffle with optional argument). But I got taken aback when first reading your post which had so many examples of the same type without any explanation.

Comment: Dear @TimothéeDautrême, I really appreciate your help, but I'm a bit, how to say it, lost in translation. I really like your comment _I can't make it better_

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the purpose of the second argument; a seed. This was the answer I was looking for.