# Getting a warning for the second argument of random.shuffle

Tags: python, random, typing

I want to use `random.shuffle` to randomize a list of strings. Here is a minimal example code:

```
import random
L = ['a', 'b']
random.shuffle(L, 3.0)
```

However, my IDE complains about the second argument. It highlights `3.0` with the following warning message:

```
Expected type 'Optional[() -> float]', got 'float' instead
```

What is this warning supposed to mean?

Comment: If this gets reopened we could close it as a duplicate of [How to use optional argument of random.shuffle in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58186496/7851470)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs for [`random.shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle)

> `random.shuffle(x[, random])`
>
> Shuffle the sequence *x* in place.
>
> The optional argument *random* is a **0-argument function** returning a random float in [0.0, 1.0); by default, this is the function `random()`.

(added bold)